# Parametrization of Dirichlet distribution

Tags: prior, dirichlet-distribution

Hej!

Consider I have a Dirichlet distribution with 4 variables, where the mean (u) values of these are known. $(u1+u2+u3+u4=1)$

Now, I want to obtain the parameters of the Dirichlet distribution ($\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3,\alpha_4$) such that the mean in each dimension is retained, while the **standard deviation in each dimension is maximized**. The distribution needs to be unimodal.

Is there a known solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution), if $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_4$ are the parameters, the mean of the $i$th component is $\mu_i = \alpha_i / \sum_{j=1}^4 \alpha_j$ and the variance of the $i$th component is
$$\frac{\mu_i(1-\mu_i)}{1+\sum_{j=1}^4 \alpha_j}.$$

So if the means $\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_4$ are fixed, you can make each component's variances arbitrarily large by choosing $(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_4) = (c\mu_1, \ldots, c\mu_4)$ and take $c \downarrow 0$.

---

Update: Thank you whuber for pointing out I had forgotten the unimodal requirement. Wikipedia gives the unique mode when $\alpha_i > 1$ for all $i$. If you want to stay in this regime, let $c \downarrow 1/\min_i \mu_i$ so that for any $j$, $\alpha_j  = c \mu_j > \mu_j / \mu_j = 1$.

<s>Unfortunately, you can't set $c = 1/\min_i \mu_i$.
When $\alpha_i = 1$ for some $i$, there are many modes since the density is constant in the $i$th component.</s>

If the minimum of $\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_4$ is unique, then you may set $c=1/\min_i \mu_i$; the distribution will then have a unique mode. (Suppose $\mu_1 < \mu_2 \le \mu_3 \le \mu_4$. Then $\alpha_1 = 1$ while $\alpha_j > 1$ for $j \ne 1$. Maximizing the density will be a concave optimization problem in $x_2, x_3, x_4$ subject to $x_2 + x_3 + x_4 \le 1$, and $x_1$ can then be taken to be $1-(x_2 + x_3 + x_4)$.)

However, if the minimum of the $\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_4$ is achieved by at least two of the $\mu_i$, then setting $c = 1/\min_i \mu_i$ will not work, since we will have $\alpha_i = 1$ for at least two $1$. For instance if $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=1$ and we have some mode $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$, then $(x'_1, x'_2, x_3, x_4)$ where $x'_1+x'_2 = x_1 + x_2$ is another mode.

When $\alpha_i < 1$ for some $i$, it gets a little hairier. The density tends to infinity as $x_i \to 0$, so there are again many modes.

Comment: Unfortunately, when $c$ is sufficiently small the distribution is no longer unimodal: you have to stop the moment any one of the $\alpha_i$ is less than $1.$

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the correction!

Comment: I don't think there is a problem if any *single* $\alpha_i=1.$  The mode becomes indefinite only when two or more of these parameters equal $1.$  Consider, for intuition, the simplest case of the Dirichlet distribution: namely, the Beta$(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ family.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, that's a good point. I've updated my answer. Apologies for my sloppiness.

Comment: You ought to rethink the statement following "the minimum ... achieved by at least two of the $\mu_i,$" because there is still a unique mode in that case.  I believe the only problem occurs when *all* the $\mu_i$ are equal.